Give examples of two nonconstant functions $f, g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the composition is a constant function.
I tried $g(x) = \frac{|x|}{x}$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{|x|}$ so that $f(g(x)) = 1$
But this function isn't defined for $0$. I'm mostly trying trial and error, and haven't been able to think about this problem systematically. Could you provide any insight as to what I'm missing out on?

If you define $g(0)=0, f(0)=1$, then your example is perfect.

$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ define $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\Bbb Q$ and $f(x)=-1$ if $x\in\Bbb R-\Bbb Q$ and $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ define by $g(x)=|x|$. Then $g\circ f=1$ is an continuous example

I can do it in one: let $f$ take the rationals to $\sqrt{2}$ and send the irrationals to $\sqrt{3}$.  Then $f \circ f = \sqrt{3}$.

$~g(x) = x^2, ~f(x) = 1 ~: x \geq 0~$ and $~f(x) = -1 ~: x < 0.$

Being a lazy guy... okay... let's have $f$ be almost constant.  Say $f(x)=5$ every but at $x=3$ where $f(3)$ equals, say, $e^{\frac 1{\sqrt{\pi} }+ 42.17}$.  Then $f(g(x))= 5$ everywhere except the cases where $g(x)=3$.  So I'll just never have $g(x) =3$.  That's easy enough to do... in fact,  $f(x)$ is never equal to $3$.  So let $g(x)=f(x)$.

$u(t) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{$t \in \mathbb{Q}$} \\
0, & \text{$t \notin \mathbb{Q}$}
\end{cases}$
Then $u(u(t))=1 ,\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$
This function is continuous nowhere still the composition with itself is constant.
If you want two "different" functions an example could be
$g(x)=\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{$x \geq0$} \\
-1, & \text{$x \lt0$}
\end{cases}$ and $f(x)=\begin{cases}
|x|,  & \text{$x \neq-1$} \\
2, & \text{$x=-1$}
\end{cases}$
Then $f(g(x))=1$
The difference between those two examples is that in the first one $u:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous nowhere in $\mathbb{R}$ while $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are not continuous for $x=0$ and $x=-1$ respectively.
Edit: $f,g$ are not constant in their domain , although you can argue that they are for restricted values of $x$ but I think that still answers your question.

Here's an easy example. If $\delta_x:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by $\delta_x(y)=1$ if $y=x$ and $\delta_x(y)=0$ if $y\neq x$, then any composition of these functions with themselves for $x\neq 0, 1$ works. For instance $\delta_2\circ\delta_2$ is identically 0 but $\delta_2$ is non-constant
